# Move TableViewCell down a little when the UIView is expanded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to move the `tableViewCell` down a little when the `UIView` is expanded.

I have some detail information initially hidden inside the view. Now if the users are interested in the detail information, they can click the button on the view to show the detail information, but the frame of detail intrudes onto the tableViewCells, so I want to change the location of tableViewCells to move it down a little to fit the view's frame.

Is possible to change the frame of the cell in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?
I have tried it, but I get an error.

[image]

The following picture says when I click the arrow image, it shows the detail information.
[image]

Thanks.

Note: My `UIView` is inside the `UITableView`, so changing the frame of `UITableView` doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the screenshot

Comment: Hope the pictures can help you understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `ContentOffset` of the `UITableView`.

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y + 44);
```

Comment: It just scroll my screen to the (0, 44),  it's not my need. I want to shift the tableViewCell down to avoid blocking from detail information.(I have added the some screenshots).

Comment: Well, you have to change the `44` to something like `self.tableView.contentOffset.y + 44`. This moves it down by 44. You can play with this to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x,self.detailView.frame.origin.y + self.detailView.frame.size.height,self.tableView.frame.size.width,self.tableView.size.height - x);//set value of x according to your need
```

I hope this would help.Thankyou

Comment: I use the UITableViewController, the UIView is into the UITableView, so this solution doesn't work. Because I change the frame of UITableView, then the UIView also move down like UITableView. Have any possible solution can solve it if I don't use the UIViewController?

Comment: So choose two seperate cell one with the detailview. . .When detail view will be open change cellsize according to detailview size and reload the tableview

Comment: You mean changing the UIView to the TableViewCell? Changing the size of the detailCell when I touch the detailCell. I think it's great idea, thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `contentInset` of the `UITableView`:

```
youtableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(x, 0, 0, 0);
```

You should fix that x value to deal with your custom view height.
Good luck.